# Extent reports issue in maven project

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

I am using extent reports in my project but it is showing me error and I am not getting solution for this error:

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3 Starting ChromeDriver
>   75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b07dc18a74666574f19176731995c-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1155})
>   on port 45800 Only local connections are allowed. Please protect ports
>   used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by
>   malicious code. [1566459495.752][WARNING]: This version of
>   ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 76. Aug 22, 2019
>   1:08:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: W3C [Fatal Error] testng-1.0.dtd:1:3: The
>   markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type
>   declaration must be well-formed. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   systemId: http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd; lineNumber: 1;
>   columnNumber: 3; The markup declarations contained or pointed to by
>   the document type declaration must be well-formed.    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Configuration.getConfigurationMap(Configuration.java:38)
>     at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.loadConfig(Report.java:474)
>     at
>   com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.loadConfig(ExtentReports.java:481)
>     at com.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest.startTest(LoginPageTest.java:65)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)     at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77) FAILED
>   CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest startTest java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.loadConfig(Report.java:480)
>     at
>   com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.loadConfig(ExtentReports.java:481)
>     at com.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest.startTest(LoginPageTest.java:65)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)     at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> ```
>       SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest endReport
>       SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest tearDown1
> ```
>
> ===========================================================================
>              Default test
>              Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
>
> ## Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 2
>
> =========================================================================== Default suite Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0 Configuration
>
> ## Failures: 1, Skips: 2
>
> [TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run Usage:  [options]
>   The XML suite files to run   Options:
>       -configfailurepolicy
>         Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)
>       -d
>         Output directory
>       -dataproviderthreadcount
>         Number of threads to use when running data providers
>       -excludegroups
>         Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude
>       -groups
>         Comma-separated list of group names to be run
>       -junit
>         JUnit mode
>         Default: false
>       -listener
>         List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener 
>         or ISuiteListener
>       -methods
>         Comma separated of test methods
>         Default: []
>       -methodselectors
>         List of .class files or list of class names implementing IMethodSelector
>       -mixed
>         Mixed mode - autodetect the type of current test and run it with 
>         appropriate runner
>         Default: false
>       -objectfactory
>         List of .class files or list of class names implementing 
>         ITestRunnerFactory 
>       -parallel
>         Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
>         Possible Values: [tests, methods, classes, instances, none, true, false]
>       -port
>         The port
>       -reporter
>         Extended configuration for custom report listener
>       -suitename
>         Default name of test suite, if not specified in suite definition file or 
>         source code
>       -suitethreadpoolsize
>         Size of the thread pool to use to run suites
>         Default: 1
>       -testclass
>         The list of test classes
>       -testjar
>         A jar file containing the tests
>       -testname
>         Default name of test, if not specified in suitedefinition file or source 
>         code 
>       -testnames
>         The list of test names to run
>       -testrunfactory, -testRunFactory
>         The factory used to create tests
>       -threadcount
>         Number of threads to use when running tests in parallel
>       -usedefaultlisteners
>         Whether to use the default listeners
>         Default: true
>       -log, -verbose
>         Level of verbosity
>       -xmlpathinjar
>         The full path to the xml file inside the jar file (only valid if 
>         -testjar was specified)
>         Default: testng.xml

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the error:

```
The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed. 
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) 
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source) 
at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Configuration.getConfigurationMap(Configuration.java:38)
at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.loadConfig(Report.java:474) 
at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.loadConfig(ExtentReports.java:481)
```

You are using an extent-config.xml file but the file is not formatted correctly.

Comment: Thanks..It worked

Comment: Glad it helped.